# How to create an emulator image with a pre-configured Google account

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools

I was wondering if it's possible to create an Android emulator image with a pre-configured Google account?

The idea is to use that image with CI (jenkins) to run some UI tests for an application that requires the availability of a Google Account for access to the Gmail app and Google Play.

So I want the emulator to be bootstrapped with the account details available in Gmail and Google Play apps.

Is that possible?